# Calculate angle on a plane in 3D space from a 2D image

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I have 2 input images of a plane where the (static) camera is at an unknown angle. I managed to extract edges and points of interests using opencv. But I'm stuck calculating real angles from the images.

From image #1 I need to calculate the camera angle relative to the plane. I know 3 points on the plane that form a equilateral triangle (angles of 60 degree). The center point of the triangle is also the centerpoint of the plane. However the plane center point on the image is covered by another object.

[image]

From image #2 I need to calculate the real angle of an object (Point C) on the plane to one of the 3 points and the plane center point (= line A to B).

[image]

How can I calculate the real angle β as if the camera had no angle towards the plane?

## Update:

I was looking for a solution for my problem at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html
There is a number of functions but I couldn't figure out how to apply them to my specific problem.

There is a function to calculate Homography using two images with keypoints but I do not have images of the scene from different camera angles.

Then there is `cv::findHomography` which `Finds a perspective transformation between two planes`. I know 4 source points but what are my 4 destination points?

Another one I was looking at is `cv::solvePnP` and `cv::solvePnPRansac` but again I only know 4 source points on the plane. I don't know about their 3D correspondence point.

What am I missing?

@Micka: Thanks for your input. I have 4 points for processing the image (the 3 static base points + the object at point C). I can assume these points are all located on the plane at z=0. However I do not have coordinates for a second plane neither the (x,y) of the corresponding 3D points.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61993219/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you need more than 2 images to estimate the angles correctly. see this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/step-by-step-camera-pose-estimation-for-visual-tracking-and-planar-markers) please.

Comment: you need4 points on the plane to compute a perspective homography. Afterwards you can warp all pixels to that plane and compute the angles there.

Answer (score 0):

Your description does not explicitly say it, but if you can assume that segment AB bisects the base of the triangle, then you have 4 point correspondences between the plane and its image, so you can use cv::findHomography.